# Nonclustered indexing with combination or on single entity for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing, non-clustered-index

I am new to database design. I read concepts of nonclustered indexing and know about the combined nonclustered indexing, but in my scenario, I have a user table with multiple columns to search on.

Table columns are as follows:

```
 userName
 fatherName
 empId
 cardNumber
```

and so on (none of these 4 columns is the PK)

I have around 50 million rows over here due to large data search takea a long time. Due to this I am thinking to create indexes on table but all four of these searches are optional, means possible user can fill all four or may be one or two of them but I was confused if I make all four separate index and one for all four then it might be causing issues on performance. While entering/inserting the data I created even a single index for all 4 column in combined but while I am searching with only card number then it takes a long time. Shall I create all four separate indexes? Would this work in combined search of `empId` and `cardNumber`.

If I created separate once then what about combined searches? If I create combinations then indices are 15 which obviously not a good way for insertion...
lot of confusion I have can anyone help me thanks in advance.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. Things like indexing and its impact on performance and system stability are **highly vendor-specific**

Comment: Yes, please tag your RDMBS. How frequently are you currently inserting? You might be suprised how little difference adding indexes makes. You should in the first instance understand which are the most frequent search columns in your actual workload. Are all 15 equally searched on?